# How can I organize many results in a selectbox using php?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, select

I have a select box that is part of a form. It is currently querying the addresses table and displaying the addresses into the select box. I plan on having up to 100 addresses.

I'm looking for a solution where I can show all the states if the user clicks on the select box. Then if the user hovers over a state it will show all the addresses for that specific state. Then if the user clicks on an address, it will show that as the picked option in the select box. This is like a dropdown menu within a select box.

Does anyone know where I can find a solution as this?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the server technology, so I am just going to go with a JS solution. What you have to do is not use a `<select>` element and use something like a drop-down menu.

[Take your pick.](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) You will have to customize the solution to suit your need obviously.

EDIT: Each final `<a>` in your drop down structure would have JavaScript to set a hidden `<input>` on the page so it can be posted.

EDIT 2: Check out this [iPod style drill down menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/):

Comment: I don't see how this would work, because I need to use the POST value of what is in the select box and if I used a classic drop-down menu, there will be no POST values on the addresses that would be showing as strings.

Do you have any specific drop-down menu examples that may help me in my situation?

Comment: If you did want to take this approach, you would tag the dropdown links to change the value of a hidden form element, essentially simulating a form control.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pre-load all addresses to the client side, then use JavaScript or CSS to perform hover actions, otherwise your user would have to wait for ajax response if you choose to load on hover action.  But i don't think that there is a pre-written script that will perform this exact task for you.  But right away it sounds like a job for JQuery.

Edition:

Use javascript's `onmouseover` instead of CSS's :hover. CSS's `:hover` only works for `<a>` in IE

Comment: I found a great plugin, but it is for Mootools and I am already using jQuery on my page. This is it: http://www.php-help.ro/examples/chained_select/  I would love to find a jquery solution like that

Comment: @zeckdude seems like a great plugin.  But if i were you, i would script this myself.  Many of these plug-ins come with extra bells and whistles that do nothing but decrease your performance.  Its like using a calculator to do 1 + 1.  You seem smart enough to learn whatever you'll need to get this done in less than a day :)